# C what is meant by the expression s[i] - '0'?

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I am currently going through K&R and I have a strong grasp of Java. One thing that comes up time and time again is `- '0'`. I believe it to be some sort of conversion, but I cannot glean from the book exactly what it means.

Example lines from the book:

```
int n;
char s[];

n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
```

Is it converting a char to an int? Is it analogous to creating a string in Java using:

```
String newString = variable + "";
```

Comment: See [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: To covert a *char* to *int*. E.g. `'5'` to `5`.

Comment: Sorry if it was a duplicate. After reading that question it is related, but I searched before posting. I never would have looked into a question titled 'Arrays K&R 1.6 chars?'. That is a rather vague question title.

Comment: Duplicates aren't a bad thing in itself: The linked question now may be found by a different title.

Comment: It was K&R indirectly emphasizing that C characters are numeric values representing ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in Java, characters are represented as integral types. `'0'` has the value of the character `0`. Since the numbers are laid out so the value of `'1' = '0' + 1` this converts a character to a digit (given it is between `'0'` and `'9'`).

Comment: Thank you, I had an inkling this was right, but I couldn't confirm it via the book. It's a little hard to get right off what they mean, sometimes.

Comment: This answer is useful but not very accurate. Take it as a starting point for learning.

Comment: @TomBlodget What is not accurate?

Comment: In Java, `char` and `Character` are _not_ integral types. They hold a Unicode/UTF-16 code-unit, one or two of which encode a character. It is true that in C, `char` is an integral type.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it converting a char to an int?

Yes, you are correct. This is subtracting the ASCII (or other encoded) value of the character '0' from s[i]. I would assume that s[i] is a character from '0' to '9'. In that case, you will get the int value of that character.

This works because the encoded values of all the digits are in ascending order. For example, if the encoding was ASCII, it would look like this:

```
'0' = 48
'1' = 49
'2' = 50
'3' = 51
'4' = 52
'5' = 53
'6' = 54
'7' = 55
'8' = 56
'9' = 57
```

So is you take '3' - '0' (or 51 - 48) you get the integer `3`. This is a simple trick, and I would not consider it good code (because, as you noticed, it causes confusion).

For good code, a function with a descriptive name should be used for the conversion, like `digitCharaterToInt()`.

Comment: Not necessarily ASCII.

Comment: FYI, that's not only the case for ASCII and required by the C standard.

Comment: Good point PaulR and mafso. I have adjusted the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

single quotes means character, which is represented by byte (8 bits), which is an integer.

'0' char is equal to number 48 in ASCII table.